# xcode8 header not found using NSManagedObject subclass in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode8, nsmanagedobject

Thanks for having a look :)

I am using xcode 8.2.1 and the language is obj-c.
I simply created two entities(Photo and Photographer) and after I did `editor - create NSManagedObject Subclass` there went error in the files generated.

One is in `Photo+CoreDataClass.m` saying "Photographer.h file not found".

Another one is in `Photographer+CoreDataClass.m` at the line saying "Photo.h file not found".

All the files that were generated were:

```
Photographer+CoreDataClass.h/m,
Photo+CoreDataClass.h/m
Photographer+CoreDataProperties.h/m
Photo+CoreDataProperties.h/m
```

The tools version minimum is Xcode 7.3 and codegen is None/Manual

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Ps, the entity's relationship is that one Photographer to-many Photo, and Photo to-one Photographer

Answer (score 1):

Just rename your files

```
Photographer+CoreDataClass.h/m,
```

to

```
Photographer.h/m
```

and

```
Photo+CoreDataClass.h/m
```

to

```
Photo.h/m
```

then copy the properties from the other two classes into the renamed ones then remove them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work for me. And I found a new problem, I cannot change the codgen for Photographer to none/manual, xcode undoes my change and does class/definition every time. So I always have a duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Photographer in the generated code. Could you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by setting Module to empty for the Class section after you select .xcmodeld file

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed it by manually correcting the header file name. Thanks for reply tho!